# In Django, whether the `session_key` is the `session id`?

Tags: python, django

In the Django database, whether the `session_key` is the `session id`?

[image]

if is, why Django do not use `session_id` as the colum name?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is!

In the  [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.base_session.AbstractBaseSession.session_key) there is a describe.

the `key` means primary key(aka `pk`), it equals to `id`.